How to programmatically track English physical manga releases?
I'm looking for a reliable way to track physical manga volume releases programmatically.
I'm currently using Otaku Calendar and their ICS file to do this, but, as I've recently experienced with Ancient Magus Bride, it's not super up-to-date.
Do you know of other sites that are up-to-date and accessible via some API or similar?
